# Python の入れ替え後、yumが使えなくなりました

Tags: python, centos, yum

現在は、CentOS6.10を使っています。

表題の件ですが、pythonを入れ替えたのが原因です。
元々は、python2.7.14を使っていて、python3.4.10をインストールしました。

yumを起動すると、下記のエラーが出ます。

> ```
>   File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
>     except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
>                             ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

色々googleで検索してみると、/usr/bin/yum の1行目を元使っていたpythonのバージョンに書き換えると使えるようになる！とありました。
ですが、python3をインストールした時点で要らない物と勝手に解釈して、python2を消してしまったのです。

python2.7.14は元々、Python-2.7.14.tgz をダウンロードして解凍後、configureして、make && make altinstall しています。
今回も同じようにconfigureして、make && make altinstallしたのですが、下記のエラーが出てyumがなおりません。

> ```
> There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
> required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
>
>    No module named yum
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or
> verify that the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
> current version of Python, which is:
> 2.7.14 (default, Oct 13 2019, 07:29:15)
> [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
> the yum faq at:
>   http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
> ```

yumを下記コマンドで入れなおしてみたのですが、上記エラーが出て修復できていません。

```
rpm -Uhv --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

どなたか分かる方、ご指導をお願いいたします。
全然わからなくて、涙目になっています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 一応、python3をインストールした際の手順についても記載ください。

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。

リポジトリバージョン 3.4.10-1.el6(x86_64) をインストールして、yumで、python34をインストールしました（その時は使えたのですね^^;
依存関係で、python34-devel、python34-libs、python34-tkinter、python34-toolsも同時にインストールされました。

Comment: python3をインストールしてyumが動かなくなったからと、yumで使っているpythonを以前のバージョンに戻して動いたので解決しました！の記事を沢山みました。
どうして、以前のバージョンに戻すのでしょうか。
新しいバージョンにしても意味がないのではないでしょうか(笑
逆光してるのではないでしょうか！？

Comment: 似たような質問がteratailでもあったので、そちらで回答してしました。 https://teratail.com/questions/216934 ご参考ください。

Answer (score 1):

`Python-2.x` と `Python-3.x` では互換性が無いため、パッケージ名や実行コマンドでも区別が付けられています。(CentOSの標準パッケージでも両者は共存可能です)

`yum` コマンドは `Python-2.x` での動作を想定して書かれているので、`Python-2.x` が必須となります。

Python-2.7.14 もソースコードからインストールされたということですが、これも本来なら `/usr/local/` 以下などのパッケージ管理されたディレクトリとは別の場所にインストールしないとトラブルの元になります。

---

元々インストールされていた `Python-2.x` をどのように削除したのか分かりませんが(`yum` コマンドからは依存関係で簡単には削除できないはず)、下記のリポジトリからパッケージを個別にダウンロードし、
`rpm` コマンドで同時にインストール指定してみてください。

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/

必要と思われるパッケージ

```
python
python-libs
python-setuptools
```

ローカルに保存したパッケージを同時にインストール指定

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh python*.rpm
```

依存関係で足りないパッケージやファイルがエラーとして表示されるかもしれませんんが、その場合にはそれらを一つずつチェックして `rpm` コマンドでインストールしていく必要があります。

**コメントに対する追記**
先に示したURLは、あなたが利用されているCentOSのバージョン = 現時点での最新版 (6.10) 向けのリポジトリです。一方で、依存性でエラーとして出ている `tkinter-2.6.6-66.el6_8` は末尾に `.el6_8` と付いている通り CentOS `6.8` 時点のパッケージです。

上述のリポジトリURLを辿っていくと、古い update バージョン向けのパッケージは http://vault.centos.org/ にアーカイブされている事が分かります。
そのままURLを掘り下げていけば以下のURLにたどり着くはずです。

http://vault.centos.org/6.8/updates/x86_64/Packages/tkinter-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。
下記パッケージをrpmを使ってインストールしようとすると、エラー: 依存性の欠如が出ます。
python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
python-tools-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
tkinter-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
python-devel-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm


rpm -ivh python*.rpm

エラー: 依存性の欠如:
        tkinter = 2.6.6-66.el6_8 は python-tools-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 に必要とされています


tkinter = 2.6.6-66.el6_8の 2.6.6-66.el6_8 は何でしょうか。

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/
の中にも、2.6.6-66.el6_8 というパッケージは見当たりません。


よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 解決できました。

解決方法として、元々インストールされていた、2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64系の python をアップデイトさせました。

rpm -Uhv --force python-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm python-libs-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm python-devel-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm python-tools-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm tkinter-2.6.6-68.el6_10.x86_64.rpm

その後に yum をアップデイトさせますと、下記エラーになりました。

No module named rpm

その後必要なパッケージをネットで調べ、下記をインストールさせました。

rpm-python-4.8.0-59.el6.x86_64.rpm
python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-11.el6.noarch.rpm
python-pycurl-7.19.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm

有難うございました。
以上です。